# Kitematic container doesn't start and getting error "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon"

Tags: macos, docker

From shell I am trying to start docker ps but I get this error:

```
$ docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

secondly if I run Kitematic and try to start a container I get this error:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
httpd (pid 6) already running
```

Comment: Please add your Docker/Kitematic and your system version to the question by inserting it.

Comment: Docker/kitematic are latest, OS is Mac OS Sierra